# Cómo copiar y pegar con la API de Google Sheet, usando python en Colab?

Tags: google-hoja-de-cálculo, google-api, python-requests

Quiero automatizar la creación de una serie de ficheros a distribuir, para lo que estoy usando la API de Sheets en Colaboratory.
Necesito copiar de una hoja de parámetros una muestra de fórmulas y pegarlas en una determinada cantidad de celdas.

Con el siguiente código, exitosamente pego las fórmulas, pero sólo en el primera columna:

```
    def apply_body_formulas_(spreadsheet_id, range_f):
  # The ID of the spreadsheet to update.
  #spreadsheet_id = 'my-spreadsheet-id'  

  # The A1 notation of the values to update.
  #range_f = rangoEpisFormulas  .

  values = df_EpisFormulas.values.tolist()
  # How the input data should be interpreted.
  value_input_option = 'USER_ENTERED'  

  value_range_body = {
      "values": values
      
  }

  request = service.spreadsheets().values().update(spreadsheetId=spreadsheet_id, range=range_f, valueInputOption=value_input_option, body=value_range_body)
  response = request.execute()
```

Cómo puedo extender este conjunto de fórmulas en el rango especificado teniendo en cuenta que cambia la columna y por tanto se debe actualizar la fórmula?